# Symfony2: Collection not bound to class

Tags: php, symfony

A Household entity has a one-to-many relationship with the Address entity.  Stepping through an edit action in Netbeans debug I can see the address in the request object, but after the request is bound the address disappears (snapshot = array[0]). So no address can be persisted.

#### Household entity (in part):

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="household",cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $addresses;

/**
 * Add addresses
 *
 * @param \Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Address $addresses
 * @return Household
 */
public function addAddress(Address $address) {
    $this->addresses[] = $address;
    return $this;
}
```

#### Address entity (in part):

```
/**
 * @var \Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household", inversedBy="addresses")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="household_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $household;

/**
 * Set household
 *
 * @param \Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household $household
 * @return Address
 */
public function setHousehold(\Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Household $household = null)
{
    $this->household = $household;

    return $this;
}
```

#### Edit action (in part):

```
public function updateAction($id, Request $request) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $household = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:Household')->find($id);
    if (!$household) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Household.');
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(new HouseholdType(), $household);
    $form->bind($request);      // address in $request
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $members = $household->getMembers();     // this has members
        $addresses = $household->getAddresses(); // this has no addresses
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if it will make a difference but in S2.3 you should use     $form->handleRequest($request); in place of $form->bind($request);

Comment: @Cerad: I'm in 2.3 but this did not make a difference.  Looking a bit more closely I noticed that `$this->addresses[] = $address;` did NOT add the address to the addresses collection. `$address` was an Address entity but it did not 'stick'.

Comment: In your household entity's constructor are you initializing the addresses collection?  And of course verify that getAddresses is returning the correct variable.

Comment: @Cerad: `$this->addresses = new ArrayCollection;` is present.

Comment: Go ahead and post your complete household entity on pastebin and link it.  You have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @Cerad: [Household entity](http://pastebin.com/C3WyyZLC) is up.  I did add a foreach loop with `$address->setHousehold($household);` that persisted the address, (so Netbeans does not reveal all!).  I didn't think this loop was necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your comment you want to change:

```
public function addAddress(Address $address) {
    $this->addresses[] = $address;
    return $this;
}
```

TO

```
public function addAddress(Address $address) {
    $this->addresses[] = $address;
    $address->setHousehold($this);
    return $this;
}
```

That will ensure your links are setup.

Still a bit puzzling since is sounded like you were testing getAddresses in your controller after posting a new address.